# Postgresql Function Volatility Categories

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a bit confused about Volatility Categories.
I read the page [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-volatility.html)

I understand what is `IMMUTABLE` but I don't really understand when to use `VOLATILE` and `STABLE`

suppose this is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sales.isallowed(userid integer)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
    select exists(select id from permmisions where userid=userid);  
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Should it be `VOLATILE` or `STABLE`?
On the one hand it has no side effects, on the other hand my system works with many users simuntinusly...

lets say userid=100 ran this function and the result was true.
then someone else deleted the row of userid=100 from permission table.
then userid=100 runs this function again. The result should be false now meaning that it was changed. Will `STABLE` be ok with it?
What really confuses me is this sentence from the guide:

> A STABLE function cannot modify the database and **is guaranteed to
> return the same results**

In my case it's not the same result.. the result is based on the status of permmison table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a doubt as to whether the function should be classified as volatile or stable, think about multiple use of the function within a single statement. If there is a possibility that the function will return different values for the same arguments in one statement, it may not be stable (nor immutable of course).

Your function should be volatile, as you can get different results with the same arguments, e.g.:

```
with q1 as (
    select isallowed(1) res
    ),
q2 as (
    delete from permisions
    where id = 1
    returning id
    )
select 
    id, res, isallowed(1)
from q1
cross join q2;

 id | res | isallowed 
----+-----+-----------
  1 | t   | f
(1 row)
```

Note that the mistaken classification of volatile function as stable may lead to erroneous results, while the opposite mistake will only result in loss of performance. In the absence of certainty it is safer to define the function as volatile.

The function `statement_timestamp()` can be a perfect example of stable function. Per [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

> statement_timestamp() returns the start time of the current statement.

The function obviously cannot be immutable, as it returns different values in two consecutive statements.

Comment: Then from your answer it seems like Immutable and stable are the same thing because in both cases results are always the same.

Comment: @java The difference between `IMMUTABLE` & `STABLE` is that `STABLE` though returns the same values *within a statement* however, may return different values across multiple runs. `IMMUTABLE`, *always* returns the same values. (Obviously for all cases above, the arguments need to be the same)

Comment: I still don't get it. I understand that Immutable is for cases where there are no variables what so ever.. but I don't understand Stable. Can you give an example for Stable?